# Div not using Bottom and Top according to it's parent div

Tags: html, css

Here is a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mcgfhL10/

```
#description{ /*Just a breif description of the product. */
    font-family:"microsoft sans serif";
    font-size:22px;
    position:relative;
    overflow-y:scroll;
    bottom:40px;
    width:400px;
    height:150px;
    background:black;
}
```

I would like the div with id `description` to fall to the bottom of the div with id `shelf`. However, it falls to the bottom of the `image`, which is a sibbling? how is this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that your description is positioned relatively and your parent has no positioning set at all. This means that the description basically doesn't know that it lives inside the shelf and is instead calculating its position relative to the image, which is the closest element. (If you set the bottom: 40px to 0px in description, you will notice that it will sit snugly under the image).

**You have to make the child absolute and the parent relative.** If you position a child element relative and then set the child bottom to 0px, it won't stick either. You're basically telling it to not move anywhere. (Relative means relative to its current center).

Here is a demo for reference: [jsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jgghpcmy/3/)

```
.shelf {
    position: relative;
}
.description {
    position: absolute;
}
```

I **strongly** suggest you read up on CSS positioning and display before you go any further. It will help you a lot if you know the foundations well.
[CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)
[A List Apart](http://alistapart.com/article/css-positioning-101)

Answer (score 0):

Your description needs to be positioned absolute, because it is not relative to the other elements, but absolute within the parent container. You also need to move your description div on top of the image.

So your HTML becomes:

```
            <div id="description"><p>foobar</p></div>
            <img id="image" src = "image.jpg">
```

and your CSS addition is:

```
#description{
  position: absolute;
}
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jgghpcmy/1/

Comment: It still looks the same to me, except now it has a baseball poster.

Comment: I added a poster just to test it out. The description is now on the bottom on the image, isn't that how you wanted it?

Comment: The description is not on the bottom of the page on my screen. it looks to me like nothing has changed.

Comment: Can you clarify, do you want it to be on the bottom of the page, or the bottom of the image or the bottom of the parent div? The bottom edge of description should align with the bottom edge of what?